# C# URL Routing Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing

So I have an interesting problem here. I am using URL Routing to mask the URL but I want to take the spaces out.

For example:

/sanjuan/ but in the database it's San Juan.
An error is thrown when I type it in because clearly theres a space in the DB.
I don't want it conjoined in the DB though.

How can I accomplish this. I just need some ideas to look into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What rob described is called slugging.

Have a look at this:

http://predicatet.blogspot.com/2009/04/improved-c-slug-generator-or-how-to.html

Comment: +1 for defining it, I didn't know there's a term for that until now.. :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what this does.

Answer (score 1):

you could replace the space with `-` when rewriting the url, and change back the `-` back to space when reading it.

Comment: I wouldnt want someone to type san-juan though

Comment: @Bry4n, you can use `/san juan/` still but I think not all browsers reads space, and most browsers replace space with %20

Comment: Right they do but I dont want there to be any spaces in the url, but only in the database. I'm considering creating a different field for just the link =/